# TypeScript + Babel + Jest not using moduleNameMapper for less files

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, less, babel-jest

I have my jest config set up to map any .less and .css imports to the `identity-obj-proxy` module, as prescribed in basically every documentation cite/tutorial in existence.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
};
```

However, I've found that when a .less file includes *some* forms of invalid css (e.g. single-line comments, calling mixins, etc), the imported object is empty.  This lead me to the discovery that the mapping isn't even being triggered, and some other mechanism (that I haven't figured out, since I didn't set up this project) has been generating class names from the stylesheets rather than simply using the proxy.

```ts
import styles from './my-style-sheet.less'; // styles = {}
import * as styles from './my-style-sheet.less'); // styles = { default: {} }
import styles from './not-a-real-file.less'); // styles = {}
const styles = require('./my-style-sheet.less'); // styles = {}
```

What's really strange to me is that when I'm debugging and I evaluate the expression `require('./my-style-sheet.less')` it does import the proxy module.  In fact, I can require anything ending in `.less` and it will import the proxy, regardless of whether the file exists--which is what I would expect.

Other patterns in `moduleNameMapper` are working correctly such as some path aliases.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^common': '<rootDir>/src/components/common',
  },
};
```

I have no idea what's going on nor how I can debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with our `babel.config.js`.  We were adding the `babel-plugin-css-modules-transform` plugin, which apparently superseded the `moduleNameMapper` entry.